# how to search for columns in data frames?

Tags: r

I have the following two data frames `u` and `v`.  I am trying to create a resulting third data frame `w` using `u` and `v` such that each value in col `a` of df `u` is matched in cols in df `v` and then find the nth value from df `u` col `b` in df `v` of the matched column.

```
 u<-data.frame(a=c("v2","x2","x2"),b=c(2,3,4))
 v<-data.frame(No=c(1,2,3,4,5),v1=c(2,9,3,1,7),v2=c(9,10,8,8,7),w1=c(5,7,9,4,3),
                  w2=c(4,6,1,3,2),x1=c(9,6,2,7,4),x2=c(4,4,4,2,7))
```

Resulting data frame

```
       w <-data.frame(a=c("v2","x2","x2"),b=c(2,3,4),c=c(10,4,2))
```

Comment: The 'x3' column is not in  'v'

Comment: sorry, i just corrected it

Comment: Still, I am not sure how you are getting the value 10 in 'w' for 'c' as 10 is in 'v2'.

Comment: @akrun sorry again, 10 is from col v2, corrected again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `match` the 'a' column in 'u' with the `names` of 'v' to get the `column` index, `cbind` with 'b' column (row index), extract the values from 'v', and create the 'c' column with `transform` and assign it to a new dataset object ('w').

```
w <- transform(u, c= v[cbind(b, match(as.character(a), names(v)))])
w
#   a b  c
#1 v2 2 10
#2 x2 3  4
#3 x2 4  2
```